Nuxt deployment with ingress
I have this configuration in my "ingress"
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-nginx-rewrite
  namespace:  ns-apropo-uat
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "false"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  rules:
    - http:
      paths:
      - path: /real-time-service(/|$)(.*)
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: frontend-real-time-svc
            port:
              number: 80

I have that url working, the detail is that when I try to enter the application, it does not load the necessary files for the frontend
It is loading from the domain, but what I need is for it to be /real-time-service/_nuxt/..
I already tried changing the nuxt.config file with the router.base and build.publicPath property

Your baseURL needs to be something like /real-time-service/.
You already have that in the path if the ingress so nginx will assume that all of your assets are served from /real-time-service/ and not /
You can test it locally and see that all your assets can be seen on the local URL. Something like:
http://localhost:<localport>/real-time-service

